# Problemas na utilização de JSTL

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Estou implementando uma aplicação WEB com J2EE, mas não estou conseguindo listar os dados vindos do ServletListarCursos para a página ListaDeCursos.jsp que utiliza JSTL.

```
  public class ServletListarCursos extends HttpServlet {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;  
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE="text/html";  

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws HTTPException, IOException{  

        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);  
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);  
        FachadaControladorDAO fachada = FachadaControladorDAO.getInstancia();  

        Curso curso = new Curso();  
        try {  
          List colecao =  fachada.getListarCursos(curso);  
          session.setAttribute("colecao", colecao);  

          RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("view/curso/ListaDeCursos.jsp");  
          rd.forward(request, response);  

        } catch (RepositorioException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(ServletListarCursos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
        }catch(ServletException ex){  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  

    }         

}
```

O ServletListarCursos enviar a lista de cursos("colecao") para ListaDeCursos.jsp.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
        <title>Lista de cursos</title>  
         <select id="selecaoCursos" name="selecaoCursos"  >  
            <option value="0" >Selecione o curso</option>  
            <c:forEach items="${colecao}" var="cursos"  >  
               <option  value="${cursos.codigoCurso}"
                        id="codigoCurso">
                        ${cursos.nomeCurso}
               </option>  
            </c:forEach>  
         </select>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Dúvida não estou conseguindo listar os valores do DB através do ServletListarCursos, utilizando JSTL.

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado.
tem certeza que sua list colecao está preenchendo algo?

Answer (score 4):

Faça o acesso à lista no escopo correto, no seu caso o objeto foi enviado para a sessão:

```
session.setAttribute("colecao", colecao);
```

No jsp chame dessa forma:

```
 <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.colecao}" var="cursos"  >
```

Ou ainda você pode utilizar o escopo de request

```
request.setAttribute("colecao", colecao);
```

jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${colecao}" var="cursos"  >
```

Comment: Na verdade, quando não se explicita o escopo na expressão, a API pesquisa em diversos escopos numa ordem pré-definida. Claro que seria uma boa prática definir o escopo para evitar surpresas, além de sempre usar o escopo mais limitado possível, neste caso o `requestScope`. A ordem de procura pode ser vista aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/875423/1683070

Comment: Testei as formas apresentadas, mas ainda não funcionou. Importei  para a pasta lib: jstl-1.1.2.jar e standard-1.1.2.jar, mas continua não funcionando.